# Mac Server - Calling applescript/automator from PHP

Tags: php, macos, applescript, automator

I've a Mac server which I'm using to host my website.
I created a web page using PHP which is basically used to create appointments. The page allows user to select date and time of appointment and clicks submit button to post it to server.
I'm able to receive the selected values on server end.

Now I want to write apple script or create automator action which will create an entry in my iCal from the data received through PHP page.

How can I create appointments in my mac serve ical with the details I'm receiving in PHP page?
Am I thinking in the right way to user apple script or automator to add appointment to my ical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run applescripts with

```
shellexec("osascript /path/to/script.scpt arguments");
```

Than grab it output from returned variable.

Comment: This should work, but remember that the user with the copy of iCal you want to add events to _must_ be always logged in for this to work (e.g. it won't work from the login window or w/a password protected screensaver running).

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how applescript works, but if you just want to issue a command-line command you can use [system()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.system.php)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to attack this problem is, instead of calling an AppleScript from PHP and trying to program around all the edge cases which might cause it to fail (user doing something else on the server, no user logged in, AppleScript taking too long to run, etc.), would be to have the server just write out an iCal file for each appointment to a specific directory. Then have an iCal/Automator action which is run periodically (e.g. every 5 minutes) which imports the new appointment iCal file from said directory and deletes it once it's been imported into iCal.

As far as creating iCal files from PHP goes, there seem to be many libraries out there that offer this functionality, including: [Benuu](http://bennu.sourceforge.net/), [qCal](http://code.google.com/p/qcal/), [iCalcreator](http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/index.php), [iCal Maker](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3619-PHP-Generate-calendars-in-iCal-format.html), and probably more. Any one of these should allow you to generate an `.ics` or `.ical` file that is compatible with iCal and easily imported. An iCal file is certainly more portable than trying to pass various bits of data like name, date & time, location, etc., around to an AppleScript.

And, for running the AppleScript/Automator action periodically, you can use the excellent [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) application, although it's App Store only now. One can manually write the `launchd` `.plist` files as well (see [`man launchd.plist`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html)).